# How to access request headers in dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am using Plotly Express with Dash. I am not sure how to access the request headers that are being sent to the server? Normally in flask, you can do something like print(request.headers), but that is not working in Dash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just verified that you can indeed get the request headers in a Dash application by simply access flask.request.headers. Something like below

```
import flask

flask.request.headers
```